# jquery select text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div>select this<strong>dfdfdf</strong></div>
<div><span>something</span>select this<strong>dfdfdf</strong></div>
```

how do i use jquery or just javascript to select the value of the div tag but not include any child elements

```
//output
select this
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("div").contents().each(function(i) {
    //the function is applied on the node. 
    //therefore, the `this` keyword is the current node.
    //check if the current element is a text node, if so do something with it
});
```

Comment: The function args are (i,node), and the test is on node.nodeName:

    $("div").contents().each(function(i,node) {
        if (node.nodeName == "#text")
            console.log(node.textContent);
    });

Comment: the function is applied on the node. therefore, the `this` keyword is the current node.

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath, you can select only the text node children of the div. Raw javascript below.

```
var xpr = document.evaluate("//div/text()",document,null,
    XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,
    null);
console.log(xpr.stringValue);

> select this
```

If you have text interspersed with tags:

```
<div>select this<strong>dfdfdf</strong>and this</div>
```

...you can iterate over them (helper converts XPathResult to array)

```
function $x(path, context, type) {
    if (!context) context = document;
    type = type || XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE;
    var i,item,arr=[], xpr = document.evaluate(path, context, null, type, null);
    for (i=0; item=xpr.snapshotItem(i); i++) 
      arr.push(item);
    return arr;
}

var nodes = $x("//div/text()");
nodes.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.textContent);
});

> select this
> and this
```

<sub>(tested in FF, w/ firebug logging)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS version:

```
function getDirectTextContent(element) {
    var text= [];
    for (var i= 0; i<element.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child= element.childNodes[i];
        if (child.nodeType==3)                           // Node.TEXT_NODE
            text.push(child.data);
    }
    return text.join('');
}
```